# Does this Python ABC interface, implementations, factory pattern make sense?

Tags: python, django

I've got a Django app and a message queue and I want to be able to switch between queue services easily (SQS or RabbitMQ for example).

So I set up a `BaseQueue` "interface":

```py
class BaseQueue(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def send_message(self, queue_name, message, message_attributes=None):
        pass
```

And two concrete classes that inherit from `BaseQueue`:

```py
class SqsQueue(BaseQueue):
    def send_message(self, queue_name, message, message_attributes=None):
        # code to send message to SQS

class RabbitMqQueue(BaseQueue):
    def send_message(self, queue_name, message, message_attributes=None):
        # code to send message to RabbitMQ
```

Then in `settings.py` I've got a value pointing to the implementation the app should use:

```py
QUEUE_SERVICE_CLS = "queues.sqs_queue.SqsQueue"
```

Because it's a Django app it's in `settings.py`, but this value could be coming from anywhere. It just says where the class is.

Then I've got a `QueueFactory` whose job is to return the queue service to use:

```py
class QueueFactory:
    @staticmethod
    def default():
        return import_string(settings.QUEUE_SERVICE_CLS)()
```

The factory imports the class and instantiates it.

I would then use it like so:

```py
QueueFactory.default().send_message(queue_name, message)
```

It works, but I was wondering if there's a more Python way to do it? Like with some magic methods?